# Negative lookahead to match server directories not properly working

Tags: regex, pcre, negative-lookbehind

Given the following 3 example paths representing server paths i am trying to create a skiplist for my FTP client via PCRE regular expressions but can't seem to get the wished result.

```
/subdir-level-1/subdir-level-2/.../Author1_-_Title1-(1234)-Publisher1
/subdir-level-1/subdir-level-2/.../Author2_-_Title2_(5678)-PUBLiSHER2
/subdir-level-1/subdir-level-2/.../Author3_-_Title3-4951-publisher3
```

I want to skip **all folders** (not paths) that *do not end with*

```
-Publisher1
```

I am trying to create a working pattern with the help of [this online help and](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [this regex tester](https://www.debuggex.com) but don't get any further than to this negative lookahead pattern

```
.*-(?!Publisher1)
```

But with this pattern all lines match because with all of them the substrings up to the pattern do all not contain the pattern.

```
/subdir/subdir/.../Author1_-_Title1-(1234)  -Publisher1
/subdir/subdir/.../Author2_-_Title2_(5678)  -PUBLiSHER2
/subdir/subdir/.../Author3_-_Title3-4951    -publisher3
```

What is my mistake and how would the correct pattern be just to match only the second and third line as line to be skipped but keep the first line?

**EDIT to make it clearer what to highlight and what not.**

Everything from the beginning of the path to the last slash must be ignored (allowed).
Everything after the last slash that matches the defined regex must be skipped.

[image: see screenshot]

**EDIT to present an advanced pattern matching only the red part**

```
[^/]*(?<!-Publisher2)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/8aH1Ssx-D7TLp9Ny)

Comment: just for a feedback did you understand the explanation nicely ?

Comment: I am yet working to deeply understand it in the way that i use your example and play around with it to improve it. As i mentioned, i am not a regex pro and using [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to understand the pro-usage of regex. I could improve it to match only the red colored part but am yet missing how to tell the FTP client to allow all parental directories while applying the regex to all directories within a directory. Anyway thanks alot to all you guys for your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex which you have used is:

```
.*-(?!Publisher1)
```

I will tell you whats the fault in it.

According to this regex it will match those lines which dont have a `-` followed by `Publisher1`. Okay, do you notice the `-` there in between on yur text, yes. between author and title or after title. So all the strings satisfy this condition. Instead if you search with a negative lookahead in such a way that hiphen is with Publisher1 then your match should work.

So you plan on moving the hiphen inside the parenthesis so that it matches and make your regex like this :

```
^.*(?!-Publisher1)
```

but this will also not work, because here .* matches everything, so when we do a lookahead, we are not able to find a single character to match . Thus we will use a negative lookbehind. `<`.

```
.*(?<!-Publisher1)
```

what now ? . I have done everything but still I cannot get it to work. why is it so  ?

**because** a negative lookbehind will lookback and tell if it is not followed by `-Publisher1`.

this is complex, just bear with me :

suppose your string

```
/subdir/subdir/.../Author1_-_Title1-(1234)-Publisher1
```

we do a negative lookbehind for `-Publisher1`. From the postition after 1 . i.e. at the end of the string `-Publisher1` is visible when we lookback. BUT our condition is negative lookbehind. So it will move one character left to reach a position where it will no more be able to lookback and say that "Hey I can see -Publisher1 from here" because from here we are able to see "-Publisher" only. Our condtin satisfies but the regex still matches the rest of the string.

So it is essential to bind the lookbehind to the end of the string so that it doesnot move one character to the left to search for its match.

final regex:

```
.*(?<!-Publisher1)$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/lE1vW2

Comment: Upvoting for a nice patient and detailed explanation. I've been noticing your nice regex style. :)

Comment: @zx81 thanks a lot brother, thats the best compliment I ve got so far. :)

Comment: Ha that's hard to believe. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs:

```
^.*(?<!-Publisher1)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/X0aKzgUhTC_PyyhO)

Comment: @sp00m You are using the same site i am using for a couple hours now and you are very very close. In fact this works, if i'm inside a server folder. But it also adds the several parent folders to the skip list. I tried to fix it by removing the '^' character since this is not the beginning of the path to either of the mentioned folders. But as soon as this is removed the pattern is broken and also those folders are skipped that are not when '^' is used.

Comment: @aelor Because the strings do not end with `-`. Look carefully at the visualization: https://www.debuggex.com/r/cpRvn2D1S1kF5Mji.

Comment: @user1014412 I don't really get it... Could you update your question with these input strings, and specify what should/should not match?

Comment: I updated my first post and added a picture to better explain

Answer (score 1):

> I want to skip all folders that do not end with `-Publisher1`

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
^(?!.*?-Publisher1$).+$
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yV0eF4)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex in order to exclude lines containing Publisher1:

```
^((?!Publisher1).)*$
```

Online demo: http://regex101.com/r/gD8jK0

Comment: @user1014412 You've tagged the question PCRE, and this should work with a regex engine that supports it.

Comment: @user1014412 Added a demo link.